# changing the background on just one web page

Tags: html, css

So I have the following css code which sets the background image to all my webpages

```
  html { 
   background: url(../index/images/white.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   }
```

My question is can I have a background image on one page lets say index.html and another background image for the rest of my pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this is a variety of ways, an easy one is to give a class to a root element and style appropriately. FYI I'd use `body` instead of `html` for the background.

**CSS**

```
body { 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
body.home {
    background: url(../index/images/white.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
body.product-list {
    background: url(../index/images/another-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

**index.htm**

```
<body class="home">
    ...
</body>
```

**productList.htm**

```
<body class="product-list">
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: I also prefer body, especially since modernizr uses class on the html tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class instead of going directly for the html selector:

```
.blue
{
    background: blue;
}
```

then call it like so:

```
<html class="blue">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `internal style` to index page, like below

```
<style>
 body { 
   background: url(../index/images/white.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   }
</style>
```

And CSS file's body will apply to all other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Add you class only to that index.html file for that site.

```
<html class="home-page">

html.home-page { 
   background: url(../index/images/white.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   }
```